# Get Official Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

Where can I confidently download an ISO image of Microsoft Office 2010 Professional Plus? Specifically:

```
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010
Product ID: 82503-003-7842932-39993
```

I've located downloads for this, but I don't trust the source.

I realize that 2010 is no longer supported, but I'm trying to help someone reinstall windows, where this is already installed and working fine for their needs. If I can't locate the ISO, I'm just going to install [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) instead.

Comment: You can get a license for Office 2010 on eBay (I checked) but you are unlikely to be able to update it. So you are better off with Libre Office.

Comment: Yeah, I'm concluding about same thing. Even if I did install it, I [wouldn't be able to update it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/end-of-support-for-office-2010-3a3e45de-51ac-4944-b2ba-c2e415432789?OCID=office_sftwrdwlds_redir). Installing it would be a bad decision from a security standpoint.

Comment: You could look [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81950/is-there-a-non-awful-free-word-processor-for-windows) for other word processor options in case this person doesn't like LibreOffice

Comment: Surely if LibreOffice is an acceptable substitute, a current version of MS Office is, as well?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn : Certainly! I let them know you're volunteering to pay for that. Send the funds [here](https://paypal.me/LonnieBest).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you wish to verify an Office ISO that you downloaded, you may check
its SHA1 hash.

A third-party website that lists these hashes is:
[Microsoft SHA1 Hash Archive from My Visual Studio](https://www.heidoc.net/php/myvsdump.php).

A trusted source for downloading the ISOs of Windows and Office is
the website
[TechBench by WZT](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php?lang=en)
(contains ads).

This website is just an interface to Microsoft's website,
from which it directly downloads the ISOs.

Comment: Checking a SHA-1 hash from a third-party source seems like a pretty pointless exercise, and a dangerous thing to encourage anybody to trust - it is just as easy to put up a list of fake hashes as a list of fake files. The most you can prove in this case is that the two third-party sites listed agree about which files you should download. The fact that the downloads ultimately come from Microsoft's website is much stronger evidence, and easily verifiable by carefully checking the URL being accessed by your browser.

Comment: If someone knows a URL, where Microsoft formerly provided the hash, you might be able to find a cache of the hash [here](https://web.archive.org/). @IMSoP

Comment: @LonnieBest Sure, and _that_ would be a useful piece of information, but it's not what was provided in this answer. Trusting hashes on a third-party site to verify downloads from a different third-party site is like trusting a poster stuck to a wall saying "the Rolexes being sold for ten bucks in the market are definitely the real thing".

Comment: @IMSoP: Some websites go back a long way and are trusted by the community, but it's a personal choice for us all.

Comment: @harrymc Then the answer should give some reason why this particular site is likely to be considered trustworthy. I could search online for "Office SHA1 Hashes", and have exactly as much reason to trust any of the results as the link you give here.

Comment: My point is, that even though you cannot trust any 3rd party with 100% certainty. The [source](https://web.archive.org/) I provided, is one I'd trust more than most. Yet, I acknowledge the possibility that any source is corruptible (even 1st party - via hack). @IMSoP

Comment: @LonnieBest My comments are about what is actually in this answer, right now, not about some hypothetical alternative reality version where the link is to a reputable archive of the Microsoft site. But yes, even if the answer used archive.org, I would expect there to be some mention of why you should trust _that_ source, rather than some other. Just to be clear, I'm not saying the answer is giving _wrong_ information, I'm just saying that _the current wording gives a false sense of security_, with no explanation of _why_ we should trust this over any other source.

Comment: @IMSoP My comments are about providing additional information that others may find useful. They're not intended to be something you need to defend against. The proper reply to my comments is silent appreciation and reverence :) Your points are correct; I'm providing additional information in light of them.

Answer (score 12):

If you're looking for a trusted source, the **safest** place to download is from Microsoft's Visual Studio Subscriptions site, formerly known as MSDN. You may find a physical copy elsewhere, but the legitimacy may still be questionable.

I think it's time to buy a current version, or move to Libre.